# Adding date to logback.xml

Tags: xml, logback, slf4j

Have tried to search for it but I keep on getting `...IS_UNDEFINED` as my file name. I simply want to append the current date to a log file. Any simple example for the logback.xml file?

This is my latest try:

```
<Properties>
  <property name="filePattern">log_${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log</property>
</Properties>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/${filePattern}</file>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regular FileAppender does not support patterns in filenames,
so you have to use [RollingFileAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) + [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html) instead.

> **RollingFileAppender** extends FileAppender with the capability to rollover log files. For example, RollingFileAppender can log to a file named log.txt file and, once a certain condition is met, change its logging target to another file.
>
> **TimeBasedRollingPolicy** is both easy to configure and quite powerful. It allows the roll over to be made based on time. It is possible to specify that the roll over occur once per day, per week or per month.

Like this:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${application.home:-.}/logs/log_.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured it out by using the 'timestamp' tag, but this looks cleaner.

Answer (score 13):

I figured it out like this:

```
  <timestamp key="timestamp" datePattern="yyyyMMdd"/>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/log_${timestamp}.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date [%level] - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```